# Bash command not found error

Tags: shell, shell-script

Why would the following script give following errors :

```
./check1.sh: line 10: Hi,: command not found  
./check1.sh: line 21: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

check1.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash


subj="host `hostname`"
healthcheckstatus=$(curl -s -o /dev/null -w '%{http_code}' http://localhost)

body="Hi, Application is up"
body1="Hi, Application is down"

mailbody=$([ "$applicationstatus" == 200 ] && $body || $body1)


if [ $healthcheckstatus != "200" ]
then
mail -s "$subj" me@domain.com <<EOS
`echo -e $mailbody`
EOS
fi
echo "email subject ::$subj"
echo "email body ::$mailbody"
```

Comment: The line assigning `mailbody` is wrong. You're calling the contents of `$body` and/or `$body1` as a shell command line.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda you should post that as an answer. I was about to, but your comment showed up, so you can have it :-)

Comment: @Patrick: Did that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The line assigning `mailbody` is wrong. You're calling the contents of `$body` and/or `$body1` as a shell command line.

Replace

```
mailbody=$([ "$applicationstatus" == 200 ] && $body || $body1)
```

With

```
[ "$applicationstatus" = 200 ] && mailbody="$body" || mailbody="$body1"
```

Comment: Or even: `((applicationstatus==200)) && mailbody="${body}" || mailbody="${body1}"`

Comment: @devnull: Modified to something in between.

Comment: Thanks. That did check one error. But i am still getting unexpected end of file error.